# SD Card corrupt

Tags: backup

I get for quite some time message my SD card is corrupt.

So what I did:

- Made a backup of my SD card
- Put the files back

However, I noticed only the data is restored, all apps are gone ... is there a way to get them back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a complete way to get them back offline but you can always log on to [Windows Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/apps/windows-phone) and check app purchases to download all those apps.

Comment: Yes I was afraid so ... quite a terrible mechanism, cost a lot of time to reinstall all apps manually.